# Throw the ball in a park

Tags: python, loops, optimization

I am trying to solve the problem of throw the ball in a park which I found at https://brainly.in/question/53867717

My solution to the problem:

```
seconds = 6
player = random.sample(range(1, 11), 10)
next_receiver = player[0]
for i in range(1, seconds): 
   next_receiver = player[next_receiver-1]
   # next_receiver at the end of the loop is the player who will have the ball
```

This solution gives the correct answer; however, it has one problem. When the size of player is of the order 10^9 and seconds=9999999, it takes longer to get an answer. In my PC it takes about 1 minute and 20 seconds to get the answer. I cannot think of any better way to solve this problem. Any hints?

Comment: I'd say 9999999 Python steps usually take around 1 second. Does it take longer for you because the billion `player` entries don't fit into your memory, so you swap a lot? Or did you include the random data generation in your time?

Comment: @KellyBundy Yeah 9999999 steps is not the issue. I just verified. Loop finishes quickly.

```for i in range(1, 9999999):  
    pass```

It barely takes a second. So I think the problem is billion entries in the `player` list

Answer (score 1):

We know that most likely there is a cycle in which we get stuck in at the end. If this cycle is smaller than the seconds count we can use it to speed up the process by jumping ahead a multiple of the cycle size

```
def throw_balls(start, receiver, seconds):
    current_player = start

    # Stores which player already received the ball and the second at which they got it.
    already_seen = dict()

    for i in range(seconds):
        current_player = receiver[current_player - 1]
        if current_player in already_seen:
            # This player previously received the ball, so we are in a cycle
            loop_length = i - already_seen[current_player]
            remaining = seconds - i
            break
        else:
            already_seen[current_player] = i
    else:
        return current_player
    return throw_balls(current_player, receiver, remaining % loop_length)
```

Note that this does not guarantee faster execution, for example when each player passes the ball onto the next person, this will behave the exact same as your solution, although slower since we are doing extra work.

Edit:

After a lengthy discussion @Kelly Bundy and I came to the conclusion that this probably will not help the situation you put yourself in with the way you are initializing `receiver`, although it probably helps with the way to original problem is formulated.

If `receiver` is a permutation of the potential targets, so no two players will targeted the same person, then the expected cycle size for N=10^9 is to large to notice/reach in ~10^7 steps (see [100 Prisoners Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/100_prisoners_problem)). A simple calculation results in a chance of [1%](https://tio.run/##jY1BCsIwFET3/xSzkSYFq9GFttDDlNqagP35JAUR8ewxQQ/QgYHhwczIa7Wez1cJKTF6mGNdtxRzan8ikoJp9gEOjhEGvk8q6o6QJah7KMYeTuMAJgmOVzVXb5OZoLs0p90HT7fa0rz5pRmtd@MUK719OtuU@f/RhpM4LPKYKp3SFw) that a cycle is reached in 10^7 steps.

However, the original problem sounds like it's not a permutation, but instead each player's target is chosen independently of everyone else. This means that two players can target the same person. In that case, there is a close to 100% chance that a cycle will be reached after only 10^6 steps and this changed algorithm will show a 10x theoretical speedup.

Comment: This doesn't same to work for the simple case of two players with `receiver = [1, 0]` since `throw_balls(0, receiver, seconds)` returns 0 for all values of seconds >= 0.  Debugging the loop_length is 1 when it should be two in this case.

Comment: There is no cycle here. All the players in the list are unique players.

Comment: @DarrylG Yes, since we are one indexed. If you use the correct `[2, 1]` it works. For the list you provided a loop_length of 1 is correct.

Comment: @HardikRathod Then there is no algorithmic way of improving the speed, and we probably need more debugging information.

Comment: Sorry guys, yes it was a mistake in the code, player = receiver. I just edited the original question. So now I think Megalng's first point makes more sense that this changed algorithm will have no positive effect. 

Plus, a player will be repeated only if the seconds > size of player list.

Comment: @HardikRathod Why do you think there will be no earlier repeats? There can be. [Demo](https://tio.run/##dY3BCsIwDIbveYocW1BZEYYIPokMKWvUwpaWtAz39LU6FXbwkuRPvo/EOd8D7w9RSvFjDJJRLLswwtJ2icipVgMk6gO7hCdsIQ52JqnjF7JjHEjVdCNlNmiMrqXRwPTIF6Ge/PTmF/HcdHANgh4940/6PNBHBET8Y67WW9O90Cies1pddClP).

Comment: Yes, I checked your example. It is repeating between 10,6,1. I take my words back. I did not think of this scenario. So you are right, player 1 completes the cycle always.

Comment: @KellyBundy   If the same scenario as the one you depicted in the demo, then yes the solution provided here can speed up the process. Only part is what if this does not happen? From your conversation, my conclusion is that, there is no way to improve the speed by improving the algorithm. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @HardikRathod If you don't happen to get into a cycle, then no, there's no significant improvement. Just microoptimizations making it a little bit faster.

Comment: @KellyBundy just to think different, could there be another approach towards solving this problem?

Comment: @HardikRathod I don't see anything besides different [cycle detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection?wprov=sfla1). Why? Just curiosity, or is there an issue with what you have?

Comment: There is no issue as such, the execution time is bothering me alot. Like what if this happens for some real-life use case where execution time matters alot.

Comment: @HardikRathod If one second for ten million steps bothers you, then don't use Python :-)

Comment: No, it's not one second. When I put the actually list of billion entries in a player list then it is a minute.

Comment: @HardikRathod I don't believe that. Didn't we establish that that time is for **creating the input**, not for the actual solution?